# Can we use http only cookie when front end and backend are hosted separately and has different subdomains?

Tags: express, cookies, httponly, cookie-httponly, render.com

I have an express server backend and LWC OSS front end created as a part of learning. everything works fine from localhost. but when the same is hosted in onrender and the httponly cookies were not getting saved.
The url of frontend was : https://pethelp.onrender.com
and backend hosted was: https://pethelpserver.onrender.com

In postman and network tab , i could see the cookie was reaching the browser, but was not saved as mentioned because of 'domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url in render'

I have tried to check about httponly cookies but its still little confusing for me. Is httponly cookies allowed to use this way (as domain is same and subdomains only vary). can we use it when the front end and backend are entirely from difefrent domains?

Frontend and backend code from github:
https://github.com/vivekvismayam/pethelpserver
https://github.com/vivekvismayam/PetHelpfrontend

**Setting cookie from express-code:**
res.cookie('x-auth-token',token,{httpOnly:true,secure:false,path:'/',domain:process.env.**COOKIE_DOMAIN**,sameSite: 'none' });

I have tried with environment variable COOKIE_DOMAIN as 'pethelp.onrender.com','.onrender.com','https://pethelp.onrender.com' Still it was not working. I have also tried removing secure,sameSite also. also non httpOnly cookies are working fine.

I was expecting this to work as the domain is same , but different subdomains